# Stats on percentage of desktop and laptop computers with high resolution monitors

Tags: screen-resolution, statistics

Mobile phones and tablets nowadays all come with high-resolution (pixel density) screens. New Apple computers come with at least 218 pixels/inch.

– Does anyone know the percentage of desktop and laptop computer monitors currently (2022) **being used** that have a high resolution?

– The reason behind the question is among other how much one should care about selecting fonts that are optimized for low resolution screens (think Verdana, Georgia, etc) or not care that much at all about fonts that traditionally have not been recommended for screen use (think high contrast fonts such as Bodoni) today.

With variable fonts you could also fine tune the stroke thickness which could only be seen if you have more pixels.

– Monitors with a high pixel density open potentially up for a UI-design that could contain more detailed interface graphics than before.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think monitor resolution statistics is a problem within the scope of UX. Maybe [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) but I'm not sure.

Comment: I agree that specific monitor usage statistic are out of scope. However, whether or not to consider this kind of hardware differences in font selection feels very on topic IMO

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think monitor resolution statistics is a problem within the scope of UX.

Answer (score 0):

I found this resource quite useful.
https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats

You can filter by the different screen resolutions:
[image]

Or you could filter by desktop or laptop:
[image]

And even by regions and years:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Screen resolution tells me very little about pixel density. (For example, in the chart above, devices with a resolution about 375xXXX are iPhones, which has a very high pixel density.) I understand that that pixel density depends on the size of the monitor in combination with the graphic card capabilities.